# Cannot GET / error with node/express/react project on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a node application with `aws` via Elastic Beanstalk. The deployment is showing as successful, but when opening the webpage I receive the error message `Cannot GET /`.

My general project structure looks like this:

```
client/
server.js
```

Where `client/` is a `react` application built using `create-react-app` and `server.js` is where `express` `app.listen` is defined.

I connected the frontend to the backend in the development environment using `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` in the react app's `package.json`.

I also added `"homepage": "my-aws-url.com/client"` to the react `package.json` since it isn't stored at the root level of the project.

Do I need to do something with the proxy in production similar to what was done in the development environment, or are there other things I'm missing?

Comment: If you ssh into the instance, does your app work when you `curl` from inside?

Comment: @Marcin I'm not sure how to do that. Is there any documentation you could point me to?